# Relationships between the field of definition of an algebraic variety and its topology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Let $V$ be a smooth complex projective variety, I was wondering if there exists some homotopical or topological necessary conditions for $V$ to be deformation equivalent to a variety $V_0$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Edit: a deformation equivalence is the equivalence relation generated
by local deformations of complex manifolds. A local deformation equivalence can be defined in the following way: let $W\rightarrow B_1$ be a proper holomorphic submersion (where $B_1=\{\mid z\mid <1 \}\subset \mathbb{C}$), the complex varieties isomorphic to fibers $W_t$ ($t\in B_1$) are deformation equivalent.

Comment: How big of a difference do we have here between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$? I mean the following: assume that $V$ is given by polynomial equations $f_i$. Denote by $a_{ij}$ the coefficients of $f_i$. We can thus think of $V$ as the point $a_{ij}$ inside $\mathbb{C}^n$ for a suitable $n$. Now, if I am not mistaken, since $V$ is smooth, it follows that there will be a small neighbourhood of $V$ of varieties which are homeomorphic to $V$, or at least deformation equivalent to $V$, and thus we can assume without loss of generality that all coefficients are in $\mathbb{Q}[i]$.

Comment: then, if the original variety was defined over $\mathbb{R}$, we can also get the new variety to be defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, and vice versa.

Comment: @EhudMeir What you say works well for complete intersections (varieties of codimension $r$ defined by $r$ equations). The general picture is actually slightly more complicated: it is very likely that a perturbation of the coefficients of an arbitrary system of equations gives rise to a variety which has no relation with the former one (it will be empty, most of the time).

Comment: And we know examples of complex surfaces that are not deformation equivalent to surfaces with real structures.

Comment: My mistake. Thanks for this clarification.

Comment: Is there anywhere a definition of "deformation equivalent"?